# Probability of pulling out the same color as the previous try

Tags: probability

Two players A,B take turn randomly drawing a ball from a bag containing 2 white and 1 black balls. The first player who draws a ball with the same color as his previous try wins the game. What is the winning probability of player B?


Player A starts the game.

The drawn ball returns to the bag after each try.


I tried  finding a geometric series but i couldn’t find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any attempt the probability of drawing a ball of the same color is $4/9$ (consecutive white balls) + $1/9$ (consecutive black balls) = $5/9$.

Since A goes first, the first attempt gives him $5/9$.  The second attempt, after both fail has probability of $(4/9)^25/9$  Summing gives P(A wins)=$5/9\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (4/9)^{2k}=\frac{1}{1+4/9}$

To get P(B wins) start with A loses on first try, so remaining calculation is the same as for A. P(B wins) is $4/9\times $ P(A wins) $=\frac{4/9}{1+4/9}$